# how to capture data from a webresponse/streamreader and write it back in console?

Tags: c#, webrequest, webresponse

I created a web request with post data then getting a response telling me if it contained something, and my question is on how to also capture something else from the response and write that in the console. Do I have to create a separate GET request? and how would i do that, and how do you get something from the get request and write that into the console.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDSyF.jpg

```
try
{
    WebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    Program.logincookie = cookieContainer;
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
    string text4 = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    streamReader.Close();
    webResponse.Close();



    if (!text4.Contains("Invalid username/password."))
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

        Console.WriteLine("[HIT] " + email + ":" + password);


        File.AppendAllText("hits.txt", email + ":" + password + Environment.NewLine);
        Valid++;

    }
    else
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("[BAD] " + email + ":" + password);
        Invalid++;
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
    Console.WriteLine("[BAD] " + email + ":" + password);
    Invalid++;
}
```

Comment: You mean like `Console.WriteLine(text4)`?

Comment: No, like get something and write it FROM the webresponse.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You want to read a specific part of the response?

Comment: You already read the whole response. I want to take something from the response and write it in the console using Console.WriteLine

Comment: You have the whole response in a `string` called `text4`. So you can do whatever you want with it now. It depends what you want from it. Use any of the [`String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string) methods (like [`Substring()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring)) and take what you want from it.

Comment: yeah, i know but my question was if the response was 'valid' how would i get like some WORDS from the response like ex, points 400. into the console

Comment: I think we're misunderstanding each other. Can you edit your question and show the full content of the response and then what you would like the output to the console to look like?

Comment: just added the whole request and response

Comment: I meant the content of the response - the actual text that you get back from the server. What does it look like? And what text do you want to output to the console?

Comment: i put an imgur link of how it looks.

Comment: So then what do you want the output to the console to look like?

Comment: the bads are just codes that don't work, i want to scrape information and put it into the console if the code is working. like whatever is on the page, the amount, the name.

Comment: like [Good]CODE, additonal information from response, more info

Comment: I meant what do you *want* the output to look like? - not what does it look like now :) what information is in the response that you want to use?

Comment: like [Good]CODE, value of the code, name

Comment: What is "CODE"? What is "value of the code"? What is "name"? Where is all that information coming from?

Comment: [Good]CODE(already have this.), money on the code, name of the game. CODE = THE game code Money = The game money on the code and the name is the name of the code. These are the additional things i need from the response if the code is VALID, to output or write it into the CONSOLE.

Comment: Then read it from `text4`.